# R Large datasets and xgboost cv

Tags: r, memory, xgboost

Apologies if this question is too broad..

I'm running a large data set (around 20Gb on a 64Gb 4 core Linux machine) through cv.xgb in R. I'm currently hitting two issues:

1. Trying 10-fold cv crashes R (no error from xgboost, session just terminates).
2. Trying 5-fold, the code will run but reserves 100Gb of virtual memory, and slows to a crawl.

I'm confused as to why the code can do 5-fold but not 10-fold, I would have thought each fold would be treated seperately and would just take twice as long. What is xgboost doing across all folds?

With swap issues, is there any way to better manage the memory to avoid slowdown? the 5-fold cv is taking >10 times as long as a single run on a similar number of trees.

are there any packages better adapted to large data sets? or do I just need more RAM?

Comment: This happens most likely because each fold has duplicated data in memory. It might be beneficial to run a wrapper code that will do cross validation serially using `xgb.train`. Do note that in this case you will have to manually account for `early_stopping_rounds` which might require to run a fixed amount of rounds and then decide based on mean cv performance the optimal number of rounds. Or just do validation, which is common for large data sets.